# Make explicit the reason to delay accepting an answer?

Tags: discussion, notifications, accepted-answer

[image: image description]

If we want users to delay their acceptance to make time for other answers appear, why don't we make that reason explicit? For instance: "you are accepting this too soon. Maybe you should wait for some minutes for others to answer."

I know that this is long, but you can rephrase it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error message, especially when coming in red banner, should be kept short and simple.

If the user want more details, he/she can go to the Help Center or the meta site to look for information, or post new question in the meta site if needed, then be redirected to the relevant faq.

I agree that currently the [Help Center section about accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) doesn't really explain the reasoning behind the waiting (actually it doesn't mention you have to wait at all), and that it would be good idea to add those details there, but that should be a separate feature request.

Comment: shouldn't the message contain a link to its explanation?

Comment: @Ooker well, essentially yes, the whole message can be a link, but still not sure it's really needed

Comment: why not? If someone click on it, then it's our fault to not giving them enough information to decide, right? So why not educate them?

Comment: @Ooker Like I said, the error should be simple and minimal. Adding more things might as well just confuse the user and make him delve too deep into something that is really not that important. That said, I'm not a UX expert or designer so might be wrong, leaving the final decision to SE team. :)